# Jquery Scrolling Element to Position of Newly Appended Element (Calculating relative offset to parent)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I've created a horizontal list of elements. The list has a fixed width and scrolls on overflow. When a button is clicked a new element is added to this list and I'm trying to scroll the ul element to this newly created li element.

Here's the JQuery I'm using:

```
var ul = $('ul')  

$('button').click(function() {
    var li = $('<li></li>');

    ul.append(li);

    ul.stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: li.offset().left
     }, 2000);
});
```

Oddly if you start tracing the variables `li.offset().left` stays pretty much the same value for the first few elements and the scrolling works fine until `li.offset().left` becomes less than `ul.scrollLeft()` max value.

You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/ePrwZ/16/

It appears what is going on is that `li.offset().left` is tracking the position relative to the document when I need it relative to the parent ul element. But I can't just minus the parent offest due to the overflow. Any idea on how to calculate this?

Note: I would like to scroll to the specific element not just to the end of the ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to:

```
ul.stop().animate({
    scrollLeft: li.position().left + ul.scrollLeft()
 }, 2000);
```

You are looking for position() method, which returns relative position, instead of offset, which returns absolute (more proper - relative to the document) position, and add current scroll state (which affects the position reading)

Comment: @Ryan King It does not, you just always append to the end. try to prepend for example.

Comment: Great looks like it works but I dont quite get the logic. Why is it that if `li.offset = 48` and I set the `scrollLeft = 180`, `li.position().left + ul.scrollLeft()` scrolls back to 48?

Comment: Because position of li element is negative in this situation. It counts from the start of ul, but the li element is added on the left of it :).

Comment: You're smarter than the average bear. Thanks!